# I have 2 listboxes with images. i want to hide the image of first listbox when i use that image in second listbox

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, c#-3.0, listbox

I have 2 listboxes with images. i want to hide the image of first listbox when i use that image in second listbox. and also i want to know the nooftimes that i added image to the second listbox. In the second listbox image should show count of that image(on the image itself) no of images that image added. 
Any suggestions..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a picklist?